# What is the best way to fire crossdomain ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

What is the best way to make cross domain ajax calls without writing custom proxy, tried using flXHR and it is working fine, but it fails in the browsers where we don't have flash, can  we do it using pure javascript?

Answer (score 1):

JSONP is the best way to fire crossdomain ajax call. It doesn't support POST request though

Comment: We need to access an existing site, and it will be returning an HTML response.

Comment: it isn't possible with normal javascript ajax request